# multiple session of httpd and Mysql connection

Tags: database

we have started using magento for one of our store,
each time we test the site with ab(Apache bench-marking) testing tool,
and it we set concurrent users as 20, 
magento starts 20 sessions on httpd and 20 connection in MySQL

is this behavior normal ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

- A session is started immediately for every request that hits Magento. 20 users = 20 sessions
- PHP starts a new process for every request. Every request that hits Magento opens a database connection. 20 requests = 20 connections. 20 concurrent requests = 20 concurrent connections